# Do data sets overwrite eachother

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working on migrating some reports from a 2005 instance to a 2008 instance.  In one of the projects I noticed the option for a Target DataSet Folder.  If I have data sources with the same name in different reports (or different reports in different projects) could they potentially overwrite each other, or will they be separated somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are datasets or datasources **within** the report, then no, they won't overwrite each other. The Target Data Set Folder option only applies to **Shared** Data Sets. (If you are using BIDS, look in the solution explorer for the different folders.)

My usual practice is to set up Shared Data Sources for each SSRS project, then when creating the data source in the reports, specify that they use the share data source.

But I usually embed my data sets in the report, until multiple reports need the same data, then I pull the data set out into a shared data set. This avoids having to manage too many pieces when deploying or changing reports.

Comment: sorry, misstyped, should have been target **dataset** folder

Comment: The same answer applies. I'll edit my answer as well, but it only applies to the explicitly **Shared** data sets.